# apa style headings koma

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, apa-style, scrbook

im new to latex and read a lot, so i startet to create a template for my thesis (must be in APA).

My only problem is, that i can't configure the headings. Can someone please help me to configure the headings of the scrbook-class to get it to APA6th Style? Or is there already a solution?

[image]

dont know how to convert the \chapter; \section .. to have the poper behavior

Thank you very much

heres my code of my settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper, headings=small]{scrbook}


\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm,left=40mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries} 

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{Das standardisierte Unbewusste}
\chead{}
\ohead{\thepage}
\ifoot*{}
\cfoot[\thepage]{}
\cfoot*{}
\ofoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{.25\baselineskip}}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks,german]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style = apa, language=ngerman]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngergam}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{references/references.bib}

\begin{document}

please see picture

\end{documet}
```

thank you very much

Comment: The APA formatting design is insane. The first question you might ask yourself is how many levels do you need? (I wouldn't use more than 3) And is your chapter the APA level 1 or is that separate? For runin sections in KOMA see [Section title with runin and KOMA class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/198830). Level 3 is basically `\paragraph`, levels 4 and 5 aren't usually defined in most classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I need  4 levels. Chapter should be the first one (so I need to center it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter headings can be centered by

```
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
```

To get the first paragraph intended too, use a positive value for `beforeskip`

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.25\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{section}
```

To get runing headers use a negative value for `afterskip`:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=-1em,
  indent=2em
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
```

To insert the dot at the end of the runin headers redefine `\sectioncatchphraseformat`

```
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4.%
}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper, headings=small]{scrbook}

\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm,left=40mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries} 

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Das standardisierte Unbewusste}
\ohead{\thepage}
\cfoot[\thepage]{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.25\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=-1em,
  indent=2em
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4.%
}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}


\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[hidelinks,german]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style = apa, language=ngerman]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngergam}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{references/references.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for the example
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Level}
\blindtext
\section{Second Level}
\blindtext
\subsection{Third level}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Fourth level}
\blindtext
\paragraph{Fifth level}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]